# How to sum up an array/list of own classes with an enumerator?

Tags: c#, linq

how to sum up an attribute of a list of a class?

```
long totalSize = 0;
foreach (ManifestEntry fileEntry in moduleManifest)
{
    totalSize += fileEntry.Size;
}
```

in ruby we can do a single enumerator which returns an array and simply sum up with it.

`totalSize = moduleManifest.map{&:Size}.sum`

i saw some enumerators in c# but i failed to understand these. 
what would be the correct syntax to archieve the same result?

i tried some snippets out of internet, but they all involve some casting which i fail to adapt.

Comment: Please show what have you tried. Had a look at linq?

Comment: tried `Enum.GetValues(moduleManifest).Select(x => x.Size).Sum();  ` obviously it is bogus but i have no clue why

Comment: What is the type of `ManifestEntry`?

Comment: `public sealed class ManifestEntry : IEquatable<ManifestEntry>`

Comment: @huanson: then why not simply `moduleManifest.Sum(x=>x.Size)`

Comment: because i simply didn't knew that syntax :P working perfect! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there - there is no need of the `Enum.GetValues(moduleManifest)` but just:

```
moduleMainfest.Select(x => x.Size).Sum();
```

Then using linq [`.Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) with a predicate you can:

```
long totalSize = moduleManifest.Sum(fileEntry => fileEntry.Size);
```

*Might be worth going through [getting started with linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) and [101 linq samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)*

Comment: yeah it's a 10 minute time-frame till you can accept questions. i did now

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine and hope that you are getting the expected output. I think Instead for asking a inline query you have to learn [LINQ](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/72d20e/concept-of-linq-with-C-Sharp/). For this time I can help you with the in line code that you are looking for: But strongly recommend you to go through the basics of Linq and its [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) before copy these code.

```
var totalSize = moduleManifest.Sum(x=> x.Size);
```